# Magento 2 order confirmation email error- we're sorry, an error has occurred while generating this email?

Tags: magento-2.1, email-templates, order-email

We are showing best selling items in the order confirmation email template.

Sometimes, we are getting this error.

Comment: have you customized order confirmation email template, please share template content because there is one variable which not filtering.

Comment: As you are talking one variable filter issue, so why is it not showing in each email?

Comment: maybe that variable related to a particular customer group, value, shipping, payment or product type.